Identifying Underperforming Movies Using Bayesian Metrics or Time Series Approach?
I have two years' worth of movie rental sales data.
I'm interested in identifying underperforming movies based on these variables. So far, I'm considering creating a Bayesian product metric that will help me determine if a movie is within its normal range of performance or if it is underperforming.
Specific Questions:
How can I design a model to identify movies that are underperforming their usual sales range on a monthly basis?
I was thinking of assigning prior distributions, like poisson for movie count, etc, but I struggle to come up with a metric that would accurately reflect if a movie is underpreforming. Perhaps I just come up with some joint prior over all the important features and then if a movie is below 5% threshold say it is underpreforming compared to it's usual?
Example Data:
$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Movie ID} & \text{Day} & \text{Reviews} & \text{Watch Time (hours)} & \text{Sales (\\\$)} & \text{Price (\\\$)} \\
\hline
001 & \text{Jan,01} & 4.5 & 1200 & 15000 & 15 \\
002 & \text{Jan,07} & 3.8 & 800 & 10000 & 12 \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\hline
\end{array}
$
I'm familiar with basic statistical concepts and have some experience with Python and R for data analysis.
Is a Bayesian metric not the right approach, should I instead forecast rental counts etc...?
Feel free to point me to textbooks containing approaches similar to this as well, thank you!
